# How to sort array with value if key exist in some elements in php

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I am working with php, I am getting data in foreach loop and in some element there is key "profile_image_max_id" and some elements are empty

1. I want to sort data according to maximum "profile_image_max_id"(if exist),So highest value of "profile_image_max_id" should be one
2. in some elements(inside foreach), where "profile_image_max_id" not exit should come with any  randombaly/any order

Here is my current data

```
    Array
(
    [46456] => Array
        (
            [id] => 46456
            [status] => approved
            [profile_image] => isProfile
            [profile_image_max_id] => 
        )

    [46457] => Array
        (
            [id] => 46457
            [status] => approved
            [profile_image] => isProfile
            [profile_image_max_id] => 
        )
```

Here is my current code,Where i am wrong ?

```
$final = array();
 foreach ( $photos as $key  $photo ) : 
$final[$key] = $row['price'];
 endforeach; 
array_multisort($final, SORT_DESC, $photos);
```

Comment: Why are there PHP tags inside PHP code?

Comment: the line `$final[$key] = $row['price'];` seems not to do anything in this example...

Comment: @MarkusZeller: that is by mistake,let me update my question

Comment: @PavelJanicek: i just want sort array by highest value(if key exist)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`uasort`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php) to do this by passing in a custom callback like below.
We return minimum value of INT if the `profile_image_max_id` key is not present, making it come at last. Otherwise, the `profile_image_max_id` is sorted in descending order.

```
<?php
    
uasort($data, function($a, $b){
    $a_image_id = $a['profile_image_max_id'] ?? PHP_INT_MIN;
    $b_image_id = $b['profile_image_max_id'] ?? PHP_INT_MIN;
    return $b_image_id <=> $a_image_id;
});
```

Comment: i want all values in array

Comment: @AmitSharma You can try this on your machine. It will sort and show you all values in the array. It doesn't omit anything.

Comment: i used this code outside foreach but its not working for me, means not sorting according to "profile_image_max_id"

Comment: @AmitSharma You can check the output in this link. https://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/c/af9db It does work as you desired.

Comment: my array is "array inside array"

Array
(
    [46456] => Array
        (
            [id] => 46456
            [status] => approved
            [profile_image] => isProfile
            [profile_image_max_id] => 
        )

    [46457] => Array
        (
            [id] => 46457
            [status] => approved
            [profile_image] => isProfile
            [profile_image_max_id] => 
        )
)

Comment: thats why not working

Comment: @AmitSharma Can you `var_export()` your array and paste in in your question? Have you checked this link https://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/c/af9db ? It simulates the array that you showed in your question.

Comment: updated my question now you can see the array which i am getting

Comment: @AmitSharma Can you `var_export($your_array);` and paste the output here? The array you showed is similar to previous except for the keys. Anyways, I updated my answer with `uasort` instead of `usort`.

Comment: @AmitSharma any update?

Comment: its working but i want reverse means i want data in descending  order

Comment: @AmitSharma Ok, I have updated my answer again.

Comment: its working now,Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @AmitSharma Glad I could be of help.